# AutoHotKey - Esc:: ExitApp not working

Tags: autohotkey

I have a long AHK script with lots of simple `{tab}` and `{down}` etc...

If something goes wrong, I need to terminate the script.
Googled, found lots of answers, mostly saying:

*put `esc::ExitApp` at the end of the script*

It just does not work for me... 
Code:

```
^#i::

SetKeyDelay, 1000   ; set to see if the rapid key execution was preventing the esc::exitapp to work, but makes no difference.

send, !f {Right}{enter}
send, {TAB 3} {Down 20} 

; lots more {tab}'s and {enter}'s

Return   ; I remember to put it

Esc::ExitApp
```

I run the script, test <kbd>Esc</kbd> - it works.

I press ^#i, the execution starts, and <kbd>Esc</kbd> does not work anymore, as if ^#i had overriding priority...

**EDIT:** interesting thing is that if I manually click the tray icon and click pause script, my ^#i keeps executing, only manual "exit script" works...

Comment: Neither the Reload solution worked: http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/Reload.htm. Once the ^#i script starts running, all other commands are ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[after much frustration]

All new scripts come with this at the top:

```
 SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
```

This command prevents `SetKeyDelay`, so i commented it out. 
BUT this then disables all `Exitapp, suspend, reload`, etc...

I reenabled `SendMode Input` and all suggestions from the internet work. Except that I'm left without `SetKeyDelay` again...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what's causing your issue, as I can't seem to replicate it on my machine. But you can try using [`SetTimer`](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/SetTimer.htm) instead with your hotkey.

This might allow you to get around any blocking behavior.

```
; Bind the keybind to SetTimer
^#i::SetTimer, MySub, -1

; Declare the subroutine the timer triggers
MySub:
    ; Execute more code here...
    ; ...
    ; ...
return

Esc::ExitApp
```